# How to implement call back function using editable plugin in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this editable plugin to edit of rows and update data into database.After updating data into database , I have to get  success message using call back function. Please suggest prefect solution to call other function using this plugin.

```
$(function () {
        var url = $BaseUrl + "/abc/abc/ItemsList";
        $('.txt-editable').editable(url,CallBackFunction, {
            onblur: function (value) {
                this.reset(value);
                $(this).html(value);
                return (value);

            },
            width: 90,
            id: 'element_id',
            value: 'value'
        });
    });


function CallBackFunction(){

  alert("Success Message");
});
```

Comment: The editable call you shown is not valid Javascript. Are you missing a comma after CallBackFunction? Also, *which* "editable" plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#id').editable({
        type:'text',
        url: 'test/edit/1',
        source: source,
        success:function(response, newValue)
        {
 callfunction();
 var data = JSON.parse(response);
        },
 send: 'always',
 validate: function(value) 
 {
 }
 });
```

Comment: Not sure where you cut & paste this from, but is this even the same editable plugin the OP is using?

Comment: it's not copy paste please tell me where is you have problem its x-editable plugin code man !

Comment: Sorry I see you are new OP = Original Poster: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean (ie. the person asking the question)

Comment: Ok Thank You !  Gone Coding Goodbye

Comment: But It doesn't reflect any return response value after, so it doesn't seem to work here.. Please improve this plugin if you can so.

Comment: Which Plugin  are you use ? rakesh